# Java VOIP framework

Tags: java, frameworks, sip, asterisk, voip

I have standalone application written on Java/SWT. And now i required to implement softphone functionality in this app.  Is there any ready to use VOIP framework written fully on java, which let me develop softphone fast without messing with low-level sip/rtp packets and media codecs?

So far i tried:

- `jain-sip + jmf`: sound quality is real horrible
- `c-library pjsip with jni`: it did the trick, but library doesn't yet support 64bit and jni is such pain with this random jvm crashes.

Now i am studying peers library, but maybe there is some easy to use frameworks?

P.S. application should work with asterisk, and able to manage calls(transferring, conference e.t.c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) uses jain-sip + jmf/fmj and works fine. Sound quality issues must be some problems outside the frameworks. Check some 3rd party examples like Jitsi to see if it is a bigger issue. Note that there is always java sound APIs too.